# false Transaction mined but execution failed in Remix IDE

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix-ide

I am getting **false Transaction mined but execution failed** error from the constructor function in the contract. I am just saving the address from which the contract is deployed in manager variable and not sending any money to the account.

```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter()public payable{
        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

//Random number generator function.
    function random()private view returns (uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner()public{
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address contractAddress = address(this);
        payable(players[index]).transfer(contractAddress.balance);
    }

}
```

After solidity v0.7, it says that visibility of the constructor is not required, so i tried by removing the `public`visibility. I also tried with `payable` visibility to the `constructor()` but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the evm(Ethereum Virtual Machine) version and VM(Virtual Machine)/Environment is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Common checkpoint in such cases is to make sure that **VM**(Virtual Machine)/Environment and **EVM**(Ethereum Virtual Machine) version should be **same**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this one below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // Random number generator function.
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address payable winner = payable(players[index]);
        uint contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        winner.transfer(contractBalance);
        players = new address[](0); // Reset the player array for a new round
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error @Anh Dang Vien. Removed the `public` visibility from the `constructor()`. Is the error due to my remix configurations?

Comment: I was using remix VM (london) till now, but the evm version was shangai, i changed from london to shangai and the error was resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.